# Best Way to Generate Random Salt in C#?

Tags: c#, random, hash, cryptography, salt

Question says it all, what is the best method of generating a random salt (to be used with a hash function) in C#?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to generate cryptographically secure random numbers..

Comment: You don't need a cryptographically strong random number generator for salts.

Comment: But it does let you generate really random strings in addition to numbers.

Comment: @Pedro: It doesn't hurt.  Also, it reduces the chance of a salt collision, which is not a good thing.

Comment: @Pedro: that's arguable. Salts must be as unique as possible. Uniform randomness does that (for a long enough salt) but a non-cryptographic RNG may exhibit biases which make collisions more frequent than expected. Using a cryptographically secure RNG is the safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library should be able to create a random salt for you very effectively.  Check it out [here](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-create-salted-password-hash.html).