# Set random Password and Salt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sha256

I want to create random password and salt.

Now I have a function based who Encrypt password like:

```
public string EncryptPassword(string password, string salt)
{
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
             var saltedPassword = string.Format("{0}{1}", salt, password);
             byte[] saltedPasswordAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltedPassword);
             return Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(saltedPasswordAsBytes));
        }
}
```

So I want to do same encode password and salt but with random values, and before encode it I want to know what password is. How can I do it?

I have something like this:

```
 public string EncryptPasswordRandom()
 {
         var password = // some random password, how can I generate it?
         var salt = // how can I generate it?

         using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
         {
              var saltedPassword = string.Format("{0}{1}", salt, password);
              byte[] saltedPasswordAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltedPassword);
              return Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(saltedPasswordAsBytes));
         }
 }
```

Help is very appreciated. Regards

> Note: I have a web application who works well, I can register user and
>   login, this random password is for recovery password  and made one
>   random

Comment: You should be not directly using sha256 directly. You should be using a key derivation function like [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) it has automatic salt generation built in.

Comment: If you're trying to retrieve the password from the hash, you can't. That's the whole point of the hash. It's really easy to create and really hard to reverse. This is why (the responsible) websites make you reset your password when you say you forgot it. It's because they can't tell what your password is.

Comment: I dont want to retrieve password, I want to made one, so before encode it. I want to take random one from my variable `password`, so I can retrieve it send via email to my user then encode it with sha256 @itsme86

Comment: The method has a `password` parameter. What do you mean you want to make it? It's passed into the method.

Comment: Sorry I change it, I want to replace password from EncryptPassword method @itsme86

Comment: You should use [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a random password. You use it to generate a number of bytes and then you can turn those bytes into a string that meets your password requirements.

Answer (score -1):

`System.Web.Membership` has a [GeneratePassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will do the job.

<strike>As for randomly generating the salt `Guid.New()` should work.</strike>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415724/best-way-to-generate-random-salt-in-c) addresses generating the salt in a high entropy fashion.

It might help if you explain what you are attempting to accomplish as well. At face value it looks like an odd requirement unless this is in a test of some sort.

Comment: fixed the llink

Comment: it is genrally accepted that Guids are not a good source of random entropy

Comment: I have a web application who works well, I can register user and login, this random password is for recovery password  and made one random